# How to read a coplot() graph

Tags: r, graphics, plot

I cannot warp my mind arround reading the plots generated by `coplot()`.
For example from the `help(coplot)`

```
## Tonga Trench Earthquakes
coplot(lat ~ long | depth, data = quakes)
```

What do the gray bars above represent? Why are there 2 rows or lat/long boxes? 
How do I read this graph?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a method for visualizing interactions in your dataset.  More specifically, it lets you see how some set of variables are conditional on some other set of variables.

In the example given, you're asking to visualize how `lat` and `long` vary with `depth`.  Because you didn't specify `number`, and the formula indicates you're interested in only one conditional variable, the function assumes you want `number=6` depth cuts (passed to `co.intervals`, which tries to make the number of data points approximately equal within each interval) and is simply maximizing the [data-to-ink ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Tufte) by stacking individual plot frames; the value of depth increases to the right, starting with the lowest row and moving up (hence the top-right frame represents the largest depth interval).  You can set `rows` or `columns` to change this behavior, e.g.:

```
coplot(lat ~ long | depth, data = quakes, columns=6)
```

but I think the power of this tool becomes more apparent when you inspect two or more conditioning variables.  For example:

```
coplot(lat ~ long | depth * mag, data = quakes, number=c(3,4))
```

gives a rich view of how earthquakes vary in space, and demonstrates that there is some interaction with depth (the pattern changes from left to right), and little-to-no interaction with magnitude (the pattern does not change from top to bottom).

[image: coplot of lat ~ long | depth * mag for the quakes dataset]

Finally, I would highly recommend reading Cleveland's *[Visualizing Data](https://www.stat.purdue.edu/~mdw/598Z/visualization.html)* -- a classic text.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer, however I still cannot read the graph. What do the gray bars in depth and mag ? Why are there 4 bars in mag and only 3 in depth? The bars seem to extend more than the width of the box: The lower left box is the lat/long for low depths, but the other 2 gray bars extend to more than 1 box. Could you please give me an example how to read the graph? Why do you say there is no interaction with mag?

Answer (score 5):

I can shed some more light on the second chart's interpretation. The gray bars for both `mag` and `depth` represent intervals of the their respective variables. Andy gave a nice description of how they are created above.

When you are reading them keep in mind that they are meant to show you the range of the observations for the respective conditioning variable (`mag` or `depth`) represented in each column or row. Therefore, in Andy's [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29480023/5548824) the largest `mag` bar is just showing that the topmost row contains observations for earthquakes of approx. 4.6 to 7. It makes sense that this bar is the largest, since as Andy mentioned, they are created to have roughly similar numbers of observations and stronger earthquakes are not as common as weaker ones. The same logic holds true for `depth` where a larger range of depths was required to get a roughly proportional number of observations.

Regarding reading the chart, you would read the columns as representing the three `depth` groups (left to right) and the rows as representing the four `mag` groups (bottom to top). Thus, as you read up the chart you're progressively slicing the data into groups of observations with increasing magnitudes. So, for example, the bottom row represents earthquakes with magnitudes of 4 to 4.5 with each column representing a different range of depths. Similarly, you read the columns as holding depth constant while allowing you to see various ranges of magnitudes.

Putting it all together, as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29480023/5548824) by Andy, we can see that as we read up the rows (progressing up in magnitude) the distribution of earthquakes remains relatively unchanged. However, when reading across the columns (progressing up in depth) we see that the distribution does slightly change. Specifically, the grouping of quakes on the right, between longitudes 180 and 185, grows tighter and more clustered towards the top of the cell.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  We aren't a discussion forum, so you should try to make your answer self-contained.  You can incorporate parts of other answers if you provide clear citations for them (link to them, using the 'share' link under each answer).  I've edited your post to remove some formalities appropriate for forums but not used at Stack Overflow.  (And, good job on a much better first post than I usually see.)